# Redux-saga fork with takevery benefits

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Any benefits using redux-saga in such a way?

```
export function* saga1() {
  yield takeEvery("DO SOMETHING", function*() {

    ...
  });
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(saga1),
  ]);
}
```

vs

```
export function* saga1() {
  yield takeEvery("DO SOMETHING", function*() {

    ...
  });
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    saga1,
  ]);
}
```

The difference is the rootSaga having "fork". I know that takeEvery is essentially `take + fork. Yet I still see people do it in such way. Any real benefits or totally redundant and should be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can think of is that `rootSaga` will be "done" in the `fork` case.

In the `non fork` case, `all` will wait until `saga1` is finished which will never happen, so also `rootSaga` will never be "done".

Practically this will not make a difference in most cases.